# Writing a background program with command line interaction

Tags: c++, linux, shell, command-line, background

I'm just playing around and want to write a c++ program that monitors my CPU temperature, *(i know there is no need to do it, i know i can get that info without writing a program)*. I'm willing to design the whole thing as a background process in linux and be able to communicate with it via command line.

let's say my program name is: **cputemp**

i want to be able to run the command **cputemp -temp** and get the temp values.

I've never done anything like this before and hope you guys can help me out

Comment: What is your question? See [ask] to improve your post, and have a possibility to get useful answers.

Comment: I was just asking for guidance. Pourya gave me the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a daemon. Daemons are background processes without user interactions. You can call it **cputempd**.
Then you need to make a client called **cputemp** that connects to your daemon and gets information.

Writing daemons is explained here with further references: [Creating a daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux)

For communication between your client program and your daemon there are different methods of Interprocess Communication although you can simply use socket programming. 
on IPC: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html

Comment: Cool, thank you i'll get on it asap.