# Background programming in C

Tags: c, bash, service, daemon

I'm trying to create a background program that has main config file which contains another config file locations and execute each of them. For example:
if main_config.conf:

```
/home/conf1
/home/conf2
```

i want to execute `./background_pro /home/conf1` and `./background_pro /home/conf2` in background. How do i do that ? I'm using below structure.Thank you

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

        /* Our process ID and Session ID */
        pid_t pid, sid;

        /* Fork off the parent process */
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* If we got a good PID, then
           we can exit the parent process. */
        if (pid > 0) {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        /* Change the file mode mask */
        umask(0);

        /* Open any logs here */        

        /* Create a new SID for the child process */
        sid = setsid();
        if (sid < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



        /* Change the current working directory */
        if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
                /* Log the failure */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);

        /* Daemon-specific initialization goes here */

        /* The Big Loop */
        while (1) {
           /* Do some task here ... */

           sleep(30); /* wait 30 seconds */
        }
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What is your question, I mean what exactly troubles you?

Comment: After closing the standard descriptors you should probably open them on `/dev/null`, since some library functions may expect them to be open.

Comment: Other than that, your structure seems OK.

Comment: You need to change the arguments to `main` to be `int argc, char*argv[]` so you can read the filename argument with the config file.

Comment: @iharob how to execute program multiple times with different arguments(argv) from daemon ?

Comment: @akiD I am sorry it's still unclear, why would you execute it multiple times with different arguments? does it have to fork and execute itself? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, how do i execute multiple times with arguments from daemon ?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You just type the command from the shell prompt multiple times, and give it different command line arguments. The "Daemon-specific initialization" code should open the file and read the configuration options from there.

Comment: Do you not know how to read from a file?

Comment: Sorry about my english :) I want to make a child process for each arguments :)

Comment: @Barmar can i make that program execute once command from shell prompt and make that program execute multiple times ?. if i execute `./daemon` it executes `./program conf1` `./program conf2` :)

Comment: Aren't you going to create zombie processes?

Comment: `./daemon` can be a shell script that executes those two commands.

Comment: @FiddlingBits They're not zombies because the parent exits.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) Looks like this was a stupid question :) I thought i could make c program that makes child processes and executes itself multiple times other than shell script :).

Comment: @Barmar how do i run these simultaneously ?

Comment: Just run them one after the other. They'll run simultaneously because each of them puts itself in the background.

Comment: I'm assuming that `./program` is the program you showed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append an '&' at the rear of shell command, then the command will run in background. 
I think, this may be what you want: daemon.bash

```
#!bash

# to stop a sub process
if [ "x$1" = "x-stop" ]; then
    if [ "x$2" = "xsub1" ]; then
        kill `cat sub1.pid`
    elif [ "x$2" = "xsub2" ]; then
        kill `cat sub2.pid`
    fi
    exit
fi

# to start sub processes
conf1=`head -1 main_config.conf`
conf2=`head -2 main_config.conf | tail -1`
nohup ./background_pro $conf1 &
pid1=$!
echo "$pid1" > sub1.pid
nohup ./background_pro $conf2 &
pid2=$!
echo "$pid2" > sub2.pid
```

Run the demon:

```
nohup ./daemon.bash &
```

The `nohup` will keep the program running even you turn off the terminal.

Stop sub process 1:

```
./daemon.bash -stop sub1
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FMziPP4k is it right ? when i try `./script start &` it outputs  http://pastebin.com/NYup97BM

Comment: and how to add stop case in script ?

Comment: Is it running simultaneously ?

Comment: The backquote (\`) means execute the command inside the backquotes and get the result as a variable. Why do you write `authlog.conf /var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: Any program can run as deamon with nohup and '&' mark without special 'daemon code'.

Comment: The '&' mark will let the programs in background simultaneously.

Comment: The way to stop the daemom is `kill` the process, it need the process ID of running daemon. That's a complex problem.

Comment: it's creating seperate process ids, is it possible to run it with one pid ?

Comment: It is not possible to run with one PID by this shell program. Only multi-thread programming can run in one PID. You may reference : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Comment: @akiD, Ok, I enhanced the shell script to be able to stop sub processes.

Answer (score 0):

A background program might be what linux users call a "Daemon" program. Please look here on [Creating a daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux) where you can find a plethora of information on how to begin writing your own Daemon. For parsing command line arguments, i recommend reading the GNU c library manual for getopt().