# C: difference between programmatically creating a daemon or using the daemon function

Tags: c, linux

I first tried to use the code in this question: [Creating a daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux)

But I got a `SIGFAULT` caused by a fgetc call.

I then tried `int daemon(int nochdir, int noclose);` function, and it seems perfectly working.

Also, using `ps -xj`, I can see the behaviour described in the answer of the linked question so it's really working as I wanted to).

What's the difference between the two ways?

Comment: If your code is crashing because of a segmentation fault, it almost certainly means there's a bug of some sort in your code (not in the libraries).  What file stream was the failing `fgetc()` using?  Had you checked that the file stream pointer was valid?

Comment: You should post your code, it's not obvious which code you are using and where it calls fgetc.

Comment: There's no list of differences; it's a matter of deciding whether `daemon(3)` fits your needs or if you'll need to roll your own for some reason. Read the manpage. Rule of thumb: use `daemon(3)` unless you have a very good reason not to. If you have to ask this question, you probably don't want / need to roll your own daemonize function.