# How to do Long polling *from* PHP or bash?

Tags: php, linux, bash, raspbian

Basically, I'm building an IoT oriented app. I created a couple binary files that turns on or off the pins of a Raspberry Pi. I have used PHP (running on the Raspberry Pi) to run those programs by executing a bash command in the past, which worked perfectly, like so:

```
exec('sudo /home/pi/Projects/calelec/rpi/on');
```

But what I need to do now, is to constantly read (long poll) an API service that will tell my Raspberry pi any instruction, and then execute something like the command above.

I know a cronjob will be ideal for this task (so I don't need to use the PHP part), but I need this to have a latency of .3 seconds.

I have read before that a daemon could work, but on that I know almost nothing. So I just need to be pointed to the right/better direction.

Comment: You could indeed write a daemon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux#17955149 this looks more complicated than it is, but I think it would be a good solution.

A quicker way could be writing a bash file, that starts an endless loop, sleeping for 0.3 sec and then does your API calls, then end and restart loop. If you want to try that, I can try to provide an example as answer

Comment: Thanks +Bolli, an example would be awesome

Comment: Just to be sure I understand what you want, before doing the example. You want to run a command or API call every 0.3 sec - in the background contentiously?

Comment: Yes, it will be a call to an API using HTTP GET.

Comment: Have you tried using `forever`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a endless loop with bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    # Write your code below, you can interact with API's using curl
    curl  http://google.com

    sleep 0.3 # You might need to adjust this, if the request takes more time to complete
done
```

Save it as `test.sh` and give it executable rights `chmod +x test.sh` and run with `./test.sh`

You can stop it from running by hitting `CTRL+C`

This script will do a `GET` request to google.com every 0.3 sec. You can write your own curl requests and commands withing this loop, that you want to run every 0.3 sec.

You can read the `curl` [man page here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)