# Detaching thread in C++11

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I want to start a thread from a process and detach it and terminate the process. But the thread will be running continuously in the background. Can I achieve this with c++11 ?

I have detached my thread like this
std::thread(&thread_func, param1, param2).detach();

But it gets terminated once the process is terminated.

Comment: Do you want the thread to run after the process is terminated... ?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, Yes, I want the thread to run in background even after the process terminates.

Comment: @KishorBhandari: you probably want a process, not a thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detaching is not the same as running in the background. If you detach a thread then you simply tell the OS "I don't want to join the thread manually after it exits, please take care of that for me". But the OS will usually kill all child threads/processes when the main process exits.

So what you want is to run a deamon. However turning a process into a deamon (note that you can't daemonize a thread) is OS dependent. On linux you would call `daemon` function:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html

I don't know how to do that on Windows or other OS. Also you may want to read this:

[Creating a daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux)