# daemon dies when I terminate parent process

Tags: linux, fork

I expect the following code on ubuntu linux to create a daemon process which is child process of systemd and keeps printing "do something".

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int pid1, pid2;
    int status;

    if (pid1 = fork()) {
        waitpid(pid1, &status, NULL);
    }
    else if (!pid1) {
        if (pid2 = fork()) {
            // use exit. return sometimes stop forking
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (!pid2) {
            while(1) {
                sleep(1);
                puts("do something");
            }
        }
        else {
            perror("error occured");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        perror("error occured");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        puts("parent do something.");
    }
}
```

But when I interrupt the parent process, its generated daemon also terminates. The daemon only left alive when I run the code on background. Why is it like this?

Daemon alive when I run on background.

```
$ ./a.out &

parent do something.
do something
parent do something.
do something
(ctrl + c)
do something
do something
do something
```

Daemon terminates when I run not on background.

```
$ ./a.out

parent do something.
do something
parent do something.
do something
(ctrl + c)
// not printing anymore
$
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run on foreground the interrupt signals generated by the terminal go to the group (parent and child). There is more info about this in [the following unix exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176242).

When running on background the process is not listening to the interrupt signals of the terminal. So pressing `ctrl+c` has no effect at all.

Comment: Thanks zomeck. I found what I coded here is not really a daemon. I found a good definition and implementation code for creating a daemon process from here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux