# plan and execute a system of periodic tasks in C

Tags: c, task, system

How do you program and run a system of periodic tasks in C? What can we do, what can not we do?

I DON'T want the code. Just if someone can give me a first vision.

Thanks !

Comment: You can use `time` or `clock` using `#include <time.h>`, but generally you want to just write a shell script

Comment: To complete @YoYoYonnY, you could use `SIGALRM` with `alarm` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784136/simple-signals-c-programming-and-alarm-function)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54618065/905902 SIGALRM+setitimer()+pause() [in Unix, that is]

Comment: I would use a threading library such as pthreads and use timers with condition variables to wake up each thread (task) periodically.