# Linux system() call returns -1 but the command executes successfully

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I have some bash command which I want to execute from C file:

```
root@/some# /sbin/iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING 5 -m set --match-set list src -j DROP
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
root@/some# echo $?
0
```

This works fine. When I do it from regular C file like:

```
int main(void) { 
     int ret;
     ret = system("/sbin/iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING 5 -m set --match-set list src -j DROP");
     printf("%d\n", ret);
}
```

It prints `0`, so it's okay.
But when I call this command from daemonized program (after usual [daemonization process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux)) inside pthread  it returns `-1` but the rule is inserted, so it works fine but for some reason `system()` returns `-1`. What could be a reason?

UPD: From daemon the result of a `system()` call I'm writing to syslog, and it has `-1` and errno - `No child processes`.

Comment: Your demon won't be able to communicate the return type of the iptables command.

Comment: What error is reported by `system`? (Try logging the result of `strerror(errno)` to a file.)

Comment: How do you know what the daemon gets for ret?

Comment: @rici The error is `No child processes`

Comment: @cliff2310 I'm writing to syslog

Comment: @narotello: please edit your question rather than adding clarifications in comments.

Comment: Are you ignoring `SIGCHLD`?

Comment: @rici Yep.. I do
`signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` 
`signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);` while daemonizing.

Comment: @rici So it there some common practice to get real result of `system()` in daemons which ignore `SIGCHLD` signal?

Comment: @narotello: `system` is a convenience function; if you need more precise behaviour, you can use `fork` and `exec`. There's example code in the `system` manpage IIRC.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3p.html#RATIONALE